# WP Alchemy Meta Box - get Meta Box value for specific post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the WP Alchemy class to add a metabox to a page editor. The page is called "videos".

On the videos page it's easy to get the value of the meta box by placing the following code in my `videos.php` template:

```
global $video_metabox;

$videoID = $video_metabox->get_the_value('videoName');
```

What I want to do additionally is to get the value of the meta box on the videos page editor,  but on a taxonomy template, taxonomy.php

I've tried the following code in my taxonomy.php template... the videos page has a page id of 22:

```
global $video_metabox;
$meta = get_post_meta(22, $video_metabox->22, TRUE);
```

But I get an error when I echo `$meta`:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_STRING or
>   T_VARIABLE

How do I get the value of a metabox from a specific page outside of that page's template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Second param for get_post_meta() is 'key', not ID. In taxonomy.php try this:

```
$meta = get_post_meta(22, 'videoName', TRUE);
```